# Setting ng-src to nothing on iframe

Tags: angularjs

I have a small Angular-app where the user can click on a link to open a popup with an embedded Youtube-clip. The important part of the popup looks like this:

```
<iframe ng-src="{{ myCtrl.trustAsResourceUrl(myCtrl.currentVideo.youtubeSrc) }}"></iframe>
```

If a user starts playing a video and then click on the "Close popup"-link (my js-code will then hide the popup) the video will be playing in the background. I want to stop that video, the easiest way for this I think is to set the src of the iframe to nothing. But if I in my controller set currentVideo to null, nothing will happen. Why?

Should not the src of the iframe be set to nothing? If I set currentVideo to another video it will switch to the other video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `ng-if` would remove the iframe from the dom

```
<iframe ng-if="myCtrl.currentVideo.youtubeSrc"
         ng-src="{{ myCtrl.trustAsResourceUrl(myCtrl.currentVideo.youtubeSrc) }}"></iframe>
```

The issue is likely that `ng-src` won't change the `src` to an invalid url value and leaves the existing one

Comment: I think `ng-if` is not required if you're using a modal instance. Please have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/tdzp6v3o/).

Comment: I now changed my custom popup to Bootstraps modal (http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp) then this solution did not worked any more. The video still keeps playing after I close the popup. Can not figure out why. Any ideas?

Comment: If I instead of the regurlar Bootstrap library uses UI Bootstrap (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) everything works like a charm. Seems like Bootstrap and Angular are not best friends. :)